# Difference in how Visual Studio & MSBuild treat the OutputPath of Web Application projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, vs-web-application-project

I am using VS 2010 web-application project. I want to change the default OutputPath property of the web-application to a directory elsewhere. This does not seem to be entirely working when I have an other project in the solution:

**FIRST:**

- Create a blank web-application project, WebApplication1
- Change the OutputPath in the project's properties from `bin` to `c:\binaries`
- Right-click on the project in solution explorer, and build.

Everything works as expected, and `WebApplication1.dll` is copied to the `c:\binaries`.

**THEN:**

- Add a class library to the same solution, ClassLibrary1
- Add the class library as project reference to the web application.
- Right-click on the web-application project in solution explorer, and build.

Both `ClassLibrary1.dll` and `WebApplication1.dll` are copied to `c:\binaries`, **but** now there is a **`WebApplication1\Bin`** directory created which contains only `ClassLibarary1.dll`

**QUESTION:**

Has anyone encountered this before? The only reference on the web I found was [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=21&ved=0CBIQFjAAOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.asp.net%2Fp%2F1431445%2F3210962.aspx&ei=QrNhTfKnEMSBlAeX1_yqDA&usg=AFQjCNG09aV8Vn687eh7hmxsgbjXfkh9gA&sig2=zzYmBqaU5kANvea-qyXcEw), with no answer. Appreciate any way to disable creation of the `Bin` folder.

**MORE INFO**

- This only happens when building from inside visual studio. If I use `msbuild WebApplication1.csproj`, this mysterious `Bin` directory is not created.
- I dug through the msbuild logs, but to no avail. I could not find any property pertaining to that path. The capital `B` for `Bin` is also strange, all paths when used in msbuild are usually `bin`.
- Last I removed the `WebApplication.targets` file Import from the web application's proj file but it did not make a difference. In fact, looking at the msbuild logs, there do not seem to be any targets from the WebApplication.targets getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your web app has default output path the same as the webapplication1 project dir. **Bin** catalog is used internally by your site to find where dependent assemblies are (see [probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx)). By Default **Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets** uses it to copy all dependent asseblies locally.

Full web app output is a site with *.aspx, *.js, web.config, bin\*.dll-files and so on. To make it copy to your **c:\binaries** directory specify **OutDir** instead. But as a result you will get the full site under the path **c:\binaries\_PublishedWebsites\WebApplication1**. And **_PublishedWebsites** subfolder couldn't be renamed.

It seems that this default behaviour is very strict. You can see internals of build targets at **C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets**.

**EDIT**: If you really don't want to see bin catalog just ignore it in svn/git/... .

Comment: i don't want to copy the entire web-app into `c:\binaries

Comment: correcting last comment: i don't want to copy the entire web-app into c:\binaries, just the DLLs. Like I said, I commented-out the import of Microsoft.WebApplication.targets file (which in turn imports the publishing.targets) from the webapplication1.csproj. It does not make a difference - which means the issue in not with the two target files you mention. Also, it only happen when building in visual studio not from the command line when using ms build.

Comment: MSBuild behaviour in VS is very strange sometimes. VS loads all registered targets files at startup into memory. If you remove import of Microsoft.WebApplication.targets you couldn't even compile the project in MSBuild. So you are using that .targets file. And WebAplication1\bin catalog will always be created.